# android application warning

Tags: android

```
 ------------------------------
[2013-03-26 22:28:01 - sample] Android Launch!
[2013-03-26 22:28:01 - sample] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-26 22:28:01 - sample] Performing com.example.sample.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-26 22:28:01 - sample] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'firstpp'
[2013-03-26 22:28:03 - sample] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-03-26 22:28:03 - sample] Starting activity com.example.sample.MainActivity on device emulator-5556
[2013-03-26 22:28:05 - sample] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.sample/.MainActivity }
[2013-03-26 22:28:05 - sample] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
[2013-03-26 22:31:44 - sample] ------------------------------
```

Comment: Well, um... Yes? Perhaps?

Comment: seems from log that everything works perfect! Great!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is what you're worried about

`Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front`

This simply means that your app was already running and there haven't been any changes since your last run so it is doing what it says and bringing you current task to the front...nothing to worry about. If you have something else that you are concerned with then you need to ask a proper question instead of just posting the console output and having us guess.

Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what kind of questions to ask and how. We need a clear question with relevant code and error messages to be able to help.

Yes, I know this may not be an answer since there is no clear question but it was too much for a comment and from past experience, I think this is what the OP was getting at and apparently didn't know what to ask